# Colaborating with 4k multicam proxy footage

Tags: premiere, intermediate

I already ingested raw 4K footage and now want to create proxies so I can send them to a friend for editing so he can do cuts transitions and zoom in/out with keyframes. The final video will be in HD.

Default proxy options have no 4K export options (not sure If I need 4K proxy option). 
I know how to create a new proxy preset if needed, but not sure which option would be best in terms of sending proxies over the internet. Both of us have high-end PCs and even h264 proxy would be an option, just to keep the files as small as possible. The original footage is 500+GB (ProRes 442), 3840 x 2160.
The reason why I would send 4K is because of zoom in/out with keyframes. If I downscale to 720p, will those keyframes work on original footage and scale properly?
Since my friend will import proxies and will not have raw footage, what kind of sequence (resolution) should he create when working with 720 proxies that will work with my original 4K footage which will be exported in HD in the final video, after he sends his sequence back to me?

Is it enough that I send him proxy folder and original project file only and when he sends it back, I just import his project file in my original project?

Comment: Good question. I know that Premiere can use proxies of a different resolution (we shoot a lot of 6k and work with HD proxies here) and things like pan-scan and zooming work fine. But I don't know if you can send a project with just the proxies. I'd recommend doing a test with just a couple of clips.